# Is it confirmed Fu having saiyan cells?

Tags: dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

So several dragon ball youtubers are talking about Fu having saiyan cells (and other kind of cells kinda like Cell) and that being the reason he can have a saiyan-like transformation, but is this confirmed? Is there any official source (perhaps the Dragon Ball Heroes videogame or the manga) where they state Fu have saiyan cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer to this question is very straightforward.

- Fu is said to be the baby of Mira and Towa.
- Although Mira is an artificial being with mainly Android parts, he also possesses Saiyan DNA.

Hence, it is certainly possible for Fu to possess Saiyan DNA.However, it is important to note that there is no confirmation whatsoever as to whether Fu has a transformation or whether that was basicall him powering up. 
If you recall, in the tournament of destroyers, Hit imitates *Goku powering up(Transforming)*, and it didn't really function like a normal Saiyan like transformation that made him stronger. It ended up improving Hit's time skip. Similarly, Jiren releasing his dormant energy was similar to a Saiyan transformation, when in actuallity it isn't.